# Pip version error when Installing TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Running into the below error when I try to install Tensorflow from command line ,

Running command

```
pip install tensorflow
```

[image]

Post this when I run the pip update command

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

this says that Pip is already updated version

[image]

So tensorflow requires me to get latest version of pip but when I go and try to update pip , it seems the latest version is already there.

[image]

Python version is - Python 3.7.0

Comment: Could you please add the output of the following?: `pip -V`, `python -V`, `which pip`, `which python`. Thx

Comment: I am using a windows machine , so ran where pip and python . both these are pointing to the Scripts directory in my local. I have added the version details to my Question now

Comment: Hmm. And do you get the same warning if you run `python -m pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: Great -- not exactly sure exactly  where the issue is, but certainly seems like you have a `pip` command on your path which is managed externally from your python install, or something. Happy tensorflow-ing!

Answer (score 0):

To install Tensorflow with pip, it's version should be 19.0 or later as per [system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements)

Since you are using lower version of pip, hence received the upgrade recommendation.

Ideal way of Tensorflow installation through pip as below

```
# Requires the latest pip
pip install --upgrade pip

# Current stable release for CPU and GPU
pip install tensorflow
```

For more details please [refer](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: @SL, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.